# Flash movie position in Facebook canvas

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, facebook-canvas

I have a little trouble regarding the positioning of a flash movie in the facebook canvas.

The flash movie has a size of 760x600 px. So i have set the facebook app advanced setting of the canvas width to fixed(760 px) and height to fixed (800 px).

The problem is, that i get a horizontal scroll bar and only 750 px of the flash movie are shown, because the flash movie seems to be aligned at canvas.x = 10 px and not at x = 0 px.

Is there a way to set the position of the flash movie? Preferably in Flash-As3?

Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Thanks for the input Niraj! Unfortunately i have never done anything with CSS. Here is my "index.html", would you tell me how to integrate your example into the html code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <!-- Include support librarys first -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div><!-- required div -->
    <div id="flashContent">
        <h1>You need at least Flash Player 10.2 to view this page.</h1>
        <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //This example uses dynamic publishing with swfObject. Login is handled in the swf

        //Note we are passing in attribute object with a 'name' property that is same value as the 'id'. This is REQUIRED for Chrome/Mozilla browsers           
        swfobject.embedSWF("example.swf", "flashContent", "760", "600", "10.1", null, null, null, {name:"flashContent"});

        // redirect
        function redirect(id,perms,uri)
        {
            var params =
            window.location.toString().slice(window.location.toString().indexOf('?'));
            top.location = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id='+id+'&scope='+perms+'&redirect_uri='+uri+params;
        }       
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Updated my original question with html code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem lies in your Flash Page. You should remove margins from the HTML page that embeds the flash and use the Javacript SDK to resize the page using `setAutoGrow()` function. The `overflow: hidden` will remove the scrollbars too.

Example CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

---

**Edit:**

In the `<head>` tag of your page, add in:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```